# Auto incremented sequence is not in order - newer values sometimes are smaller than prev one?

Tags: database, oracle, sequence

I understand that sometimes there are gaps in the auto generated db sequence, However in my case in the last year, I have new values generated which are not only in order, but also smaller than the prev generated one (8 times in the past year). We have a complex algorithm of calculating ages, based on this auto gen ID, but it is frequently messed up and causing issues. Below is a snippet of the values, can you please help in why it is happening. (I cannot update Oracle, due to some high customisations created earlier)

The below is sorted using the Auto gen sequence. Notice the first two and the last two, on how the sequence has mis-generated.

Auto Gen ID  --- Timestamp

1046746686 ---  2018-05-16 06:52:26
1046746689  --- 2018-05-16 06:50:42
1046746690  --- 2018-05-16 06:50:52
1046746692 ---  2018-05-16 06:52:52
1046746705  --- 2018-05-16 06:55:41
1046746773  --- 2018-05-16 10:50:27
1046746774  --- 2018-05-16 10:36:27

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Auto-Increment in Oracle APEX occasionally skips a chunck of numbers when incrementing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7584718/sql-auto-increment-in-oracle-apex-occasionally-skips-a-chunck-of-numbers-when-in)

Comment: How are the sequence value and the timestamp generated?  When the row is inserted into the table, does it use `nextval` and `systimestamp`?  Or does the application read the `nextval`, generate a timestamp, do some processing, and then insert them both?  Or something else?

Comment: This question gets asked fairly often on this site.  Long story short, auto increment sequences don't have to be continuous to meet the criteria of being unique etc.

Comment: There can be one possibility that your application is running on two different DB using some replication like 'GOLDEN GATE"  for real time replication and both of DB having same sequence name but different sequence values. And from your Load Balancer the session some time goes to DB1 and sometime goes to DB2.

Comment: You don't mention if you are using RAC. This can happen as per this question [Oracle RAC and sequences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4866959/oracle-rac-and-sequences)